Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 in Postman
Testing a basic project in postman but getting

"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080".

I am uploading an image in multipart file through postman in form-data along with JSON objects.
Below is my application.properties code.
spring.application.name=products-desc

# DataSource Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


# JPA / Hibernate Configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


# File Upload Configuration
# Adjust the following properties according to your file upload requirements
# Maximum allowed size of a single file in bytes
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
# Maximum allowed size of the entire multipart request in bytes
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
# Temporary directory used to store uploaded files
spring.servlet.multipart.location=uploads

server.port=8080



Below is the run from Intellij
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50703:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.10.2\junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\workspace-intellij-idea\products-desc\target\test-classes;C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\workspace-intellij-idea\products-desc\target\classes;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.6\spring-aop-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.22\aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.1.6\spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.4.4.Final\hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.1.2\jandex-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.6.0\classmate-1.6.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.13\byte-buddy-1.14.13.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.5\jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.5\jaxb-core-4.0.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.2\angus-activation-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.5\txw2-4.0.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.2\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.13.0\antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.2.5\spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.2.5\spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.1.6\spring-orm-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.6\spring-context-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.6\spring-tx-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.6\spring-beans-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.13\slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.1.6\spring-aspects-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-validation-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.14\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.14\logback-core-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.21.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.13\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\8.0.1.Final\hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\3.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.4\jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.4\jackson-annotations-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.4\jackson-core-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.6\spring-web-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.5\micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.5\micrometer-commons-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.6\spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.6\spring-expression-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\3.2.5\spring-boot-devtools-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.5\spring-boot-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.5\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.3.0\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-test-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\3.2.5\spring-boot-test-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\3.2.5\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.9.0\json-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.3\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.5.1\json-smart-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.5.1\accessors-smart-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.6\asm-9.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.24.2\assertj-core-3.24.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\awaitility\awaitility\4.2.1\awaitility-4.2.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest\2.2\hamcrest-2.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter\5.10.2\junit-jupiter-5.10.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.10.2\junit-jupiter-api-5.10.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.3.0\opentest4j-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.10.2\junit-platform-commons-1.10.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.2\apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-params\5.10.2\junit-jupiter-params-5.10.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.10.2\junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.10.2\junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\5.7.0\mockito-core-5.7.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.13\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.13.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\3.3\objenesis-3.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-junit-jupiter\5.7.0\mockito-junit-jupiter-5.7.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.1\jsonassert-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.6\spring-core-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.6\spring-jcl-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\6.1.6\spring-test-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.9.1\xmlunit-core-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.32\lombok-1.18.32.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 @w@C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit.tmp @C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit.tmp -socket50702
18:16:07.933 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.smart.application.ProductsDescApplicationTests]: ProductsDescApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
18:16:08.238 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.smart.application.ProductsDescApplication for test class com.smart.application.ProductsDescApplicationTests
18:16:08.643 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener -- Restart disabled due to context in which it is running

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.5)

2024-05-07T18:16:09.300+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] c.s.a.ProductsDescApplicationTests       : Starting ProductsDescApplicationTests using Java 17.0.9 with PID 7416 (started by ASUS in C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\workspace-intellij-idea\products-desc)
2024-05-07T18:16:09.303+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] c.s.a.ProductsDescApplicationTests       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-07T18:16:10.679+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-07T18:16:10.732+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 37 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-05-07T18:16:11.828+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-05-07T18:16:12.021+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final
2024-05-07T18:16:12.101+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-05-07T18:16:12.672+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-05-07T18:16:12.737+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-05-07T18:16:13.531+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@510da778
2024-05-07T18:16:13.535+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-05-07T18:16:15.192+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-05-07T18:16:15.204+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-07T18:16:15.668+05:30  WARN 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-05-07T18:16:16.948+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [           main] c.s.a.ProductsDescApplicationTests       : Started ProductsDescApplicationTests in 8.311 seconds (process running for 11.198)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2024-05-07T18:16:18.839+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-07T18:16:18.844+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-05-07T18:16:18.865+05:30  INFO 7416 --- [products-desc] [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0


I thought error might be in localhost server,

tried reinstalling postman,
tried using postman web,
turned off defender firewall,
no VPN or proxy servers. Can't find solution for this also
tried changing port numbers but no use.
Rechecked the controller endpoints, URI.

For reference below is pom.xml which contains just basic starter dependencies:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.smart</groupId>
    <artifactId>products-desc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>products-desc</name>
    <description>products-desc</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



Your app stops right after starting (Process finished with exit code 0) meaning there are no non-daemon threads running. Unless you changed the default logging settings, you should also see a log about the web-server and the port it's listening on (eg Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '') but you don't, which hints to something missing from your class-path. If you manually added the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, try
reimporting your maven project (refresh icon in the maven tool window), to ensure all updated dependencies are on the class-path, and retry.

@Morfic I created a new project, tomcat server is started but when I go to test on postman I am getting 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource api/products.\r\n\tat org.' 404 Resource Not found Checked the endpoints , the URI, the controller class

The first error was indeed related to your application not running.
The second error is related to you not calling the proper URL or not calling it in the way that your URL expects. Therefore, api/product is somehow not reachable when you call it.
To further debug this, it would be helpful if you could share your controller code and the method you use to call it (perhaps you are using GET rather than POST, or vice versa), along with some other pieces of code (security, config, etc)
P.S.: Another thing you can do is to create a very simple endpoint in the same controller class, let's say an alive endpoint which just returns a simple JSON or string and shows that the application is running (or you can enable the actuator for that matter). In that case, you can validate that at least your Spring Security and other configurations, and your controller bean are alive, and you are only calling your other endpoint in the wrong way.
